# c# Prism connection between two ViewModels

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, prism, viewmodel

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application, which uses Prism for MVVM, and I have some problems, more precisely in establishing a connection between two ViewModels.

In my MainPage I have a UserControl and a Label(TextBlock), the UserControl have a picker(ComboBox).

What I want to achieve is to establish a connection between the MainPageViewModels and UserControlViewModel, so that each time the user changes the selection in the picker, the UserControlViewModel informs MainPageViewModels then, it can change the value of the Label(TextBlock).

**There is my code:**

MainPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyNewApp.Views"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
            x:Class="MyNewApp.Views.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <views:UserControl x:Name="UserControl"/>

            <Label Text="{Binding NumberChosen}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPageViewModel:

```
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace MyNewApp.ViewModels
{
    class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private int _NumberChosen;
        public int NumberChosen
        {
            get { return _NumberChosen; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _NumberChosen, value); }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            // Must Read the value on the picker of the UserControl.
            NumberChosen = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="MyNewApp.Views.UserControl">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Pick a number:"/>

    <Picker Grid.Row="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding NumericSource}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding NumberSelected}"
            />

</Grid>
```

UserControlViewModel

```
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MyNewApp.ViewModels
{
    public class UserControlViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> NumericSource { get; set; }

        private int _NumberSelected;
        public int NumberSelected
        {
            get { return _NumberSelected; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _NumberSelected, value); }
        }

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            var source = SourceCreator();

            NumericSource = source;
            NumberSelected = source[0];
        }

        ObservableCollection<int> SourceCreator()
        {
            ObservableCollection<int> sourceCreator = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            for (int i = 21; i < 99; i++)
            {
                sourceCreator.Add(i);
            }
            return sourceCreator;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Usually you don't use a viewmodel for the UserControl even if you do it should not be dependent on the other view model but you can just bind the PageViewModel to the UserControl to have better control over the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Define bindable property in UserControl called NumberChosen

2- in UserControl's Xaml, bind NumberChosen to NumberSelected (SelectedItem of your picker) ( You can bind it SelectedItem of your picker directly too)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-control-to-control-in-xamarin-forms/

3- In main page, if you want to show that in your view only, you can bind control to control as mentioned before.

4- You can also bind ChosenNumber of user control to a property in your main view model too